# How to draw bezier curves with OpenGL more precisely?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, bezier

I have a set of points and I want to draw bezier curve using this set. What is important for me is that the curve should be drawn in a precise way, i.e. closely approximate to the original data values.

I use the following code:

```
gl.glMap1f(GL.GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3,0.0f,1.0f,3,numLines+1,ctrlpointBuf);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3);

gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (int i=0;i<=100;i++)
    gl.glEvalCoord1f(i/100.0f);
gl.glEnd();
```

And with this code I get this picture (teal - original line, black - bezier curve), which can be hardly called precise.

[image]

Is there any way to get the curve more close to the original points?

Comment: This question is very confused. First, that's not a Bezier curve. Or at least, it's not a piecewise cubic Bezier curve. It might be an n-th degree Bezier (where n is the number of control points minus 1), but it isn't a piecewise Bezier.

Comment: If this is an n-th degree Bezier curve, then you're not going to get it any closer to the control points *without* it no longer being a Bezier curve. That's how Bezier curves are defined: the two end-points are on the curve, and the curve *approximates* the shape outlined by the other control points. So a curve that more closely follows the control points won't be a Bezier curve anymore.

Comment: So what are you looking for: a different kind of spline curve, or how to properly generate a piecewise cubic Bezier?

Comment: Your teal curve looks like a set of straight line segments.  That should be easy to draw, no Beziers needed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. I do not really familiar with computer graphics area.. I need just a spline, so that my teal line would look more smooth.